# hiding namespaces in C++

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I've read some answers to other similar questions on SO that seemed to indicate that it was possible to hide a namespace away (for the purpose of hiding implementation details), but they didn't say how.

So for example, if I wanted a `namespace A` which contained a `namespace B`, and `B` had some nasty implementation details for features in `A` that I wanted hidden from the end user, is there some sort of linker trickery that I can use so that `B` is not visible outside of `A`, but `A` is still visible to the rest of the program?

Comment: I think the only "trickery" involved here is "avoid putting `B` in the header file".

Comment: Don't name the namespace "B", name it "Internal_B" :-)

Comment: ... avoid putting B in the header file? what does that mean exactly? I have to put it somewhere...

Comment: or else use class B and private static funcs

Comment: I use the convention that any namespace whose name ends with `detail` is private (just like Boost does). If the end user touches it and gets burned, or I change something in it and break their code, I don't care.

Comment: @Greg Do you mean I should declare the interfaces for whatever classes I need in A, and then put a `namespace B` only in my implementation file? That sounds like it would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of namespaces is to avoid the name clashes. That is essentially all. They do not provide any features to hide anything. Although for certain extend they force to write `namesp_name::sometinng`. This may make the user think if this is worth doing or not.

What the comments above suggest, is basically splitting your header into public header and private header. Private header is included only in your cpp file and it is not expected to be included in the upper layer code. This works in many cases and this is helpful but it does not solve all problems.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "but it does not solve all problems"? Does that mean that if `namespace B` is only defined in the cpp files for my `A` namespace, `B` will still be accessible from outside of those two places?

Comment: "Does not solve all the problems" refers to the concept of public and private header files. This concept itself has nothing to do with the namespaces.

Comment: When the program is compiled, everything that is visible comes only from header files that are included into the current compilation. Information from earlier object files or from header files that were included elsewhere cannot be accessed.

Comment: "public and private header files"? I wasn't aware that there was such a thing as a "private header file". What would be the behavior of such a thing?

Comment: In case if your implementation contains more than one cpp file, it makes sense to create a private header.

Comment: Does it? I'm still not sure what you mean by "private".

Comment: Private means that it is disadvised to include this header into application code. You can name it something like `Blah_internal_details.h`. This will not prevent from including it, but this will make it obvious that this is not a regular header.

Comment: Oh, okay, so you're saying that "it doesn't solve all problems" because you can't **prevent** the end user from including your `*_detail.h` file(s), so it's not fail-safe, but as long as the end user isn't a complete **dunce**, this method will work. Thank you, +1 good answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be talking about is a "Pimpl" pattern, and/or Handle/Body idiom.  Or a few other names you can come up with.  A really short example of such is on the boost [Smart Pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Handle/Body) page.  It explains how you can declare a class with an incomplete type into a smart pointer, and then define the implementation somewhere else.  This "hides" it from an API user, in that the implementation for the "inner" class can change without re-compilation by anybody but the library creator, because the size is only in implementations, not in header files.  Only the size of the "public" class is known, and remains constant.  Read through the two .cpp files and the one .hpp file and see if it makes sense as to why it works.

I hope that's related to what you're trying to do.